# Estoy tratando de recorrer 1na lista con otra lista dentro

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un sistema de solicitudes, y se deben mostrar en un data table, pero esta solo debe mostrar el Status mas reciente( el ulitmo de la lista ) pero tambien debo de verificar el id de la solicitud. Pero al ejecutar el codigo se queda colgado y el navegador lanza un error de Out of Memory:

`

```
    var list_idHelpsSol = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 10] // es una lista con los id de las solicitudes realizadas
    var list_StatusSol = [[1, "enviado", 1, "enviado", 1, "enviado"]] // lista de los los Status con una lista dentro que contiene el id de la solicitud y el Status

    var list = []
        for (let i = 0; i < list_idHelpsSol.length; i++) {
            const id_sol = list_idHelpsSol[i];

            for (let i = 0; i < list_StatusSol.length; i++) {
                const id_status = list_StatusSol[i];
                if (id_sol == id_status["id_Sol"]) { // verifico que haya una lista con dicho id y si no es asi agrega otra lista con el id y el status

                    if (list.length) {// si la lista NO esta vacia, recorrera dicha lista en busca de una lista con un diccionario que tenga el mismo id_Sol
                        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                            const lista_lista = list[i];

                            if (lista_lista[0] == id_sol) {
                                lista_lista.push( id_status["id_Sol"] )
                                lista_lista.push( id_status["Type_Status"] )
                            }

                            list.push( [ id_status["id_Sol"], id_status["Type_Status"] ]   )

                        }
                        
                    }
                    else{
                        list.push( [ id_status["id_Sol"], id_status["Type_Status"] ]   )
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                }

            }
```

Comment: ¿Qué intentas hacer? Si explicaras lo que quieres tal vez se te podría ayudar mejor y darte una alternativa mucho más eficiente a 4 `for` anidados. _"No se por qué mi código no funciona_" no dice absolutamente nada. Por favor, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/538126/edit) y describe con palabras lo que intentas hacer. Agrega lo que esperas obtener cuando ejecutes tu código.

Comment: Si explicas que significan los valores de `list_idHelpsSol` y de `list_StatusSol` y que esperas obtener de ellos sería mucho mas fácil ayudarte. Como dice Jaime, es probable que todos esos ciclos anidados no sea lo mas eficiente y te podamos ayudar con alguna otra alternativa.

Comment: ya especifique el significado de los valores de `list_idHelpsSol` y de  `list_StatusSol`

Answer (score 0):

Está intentanto también apilar un montón de objetos en una lista, y eso tarde o temprano llenará la memoria, lo que puede hacer para solucionar esto es hacer una lista de un tamaño específico, eliminar el primer elemento, mover todos los elementos al espacio anterior al que están y añadir en el último espacio de la lista el nuevo elemento que va a añadir.
Ejemplo:

```
var Lista = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; //10 elementos...
function Insertar(dato) {
       for (i = 0; i < Lista.length - 1; i++)
       {
          Lista[i] = Lista[i+1];
       }
           Lista[Lista.length -1] = dato;
      }
```

Comment: 'dato' puede ser también una lista, por lo que también resultaría en una lista dentro de una lista